# Python3 add multiple line of strings into one list

Tags: python-3.x

I have strings in multiple lines, but my requirement is to have those strings in one list

```
['arn:aws:iam::****:saml/Prod']
['arn:aws:iam::***:saml/Test']
['arn:aws:iam::*****:saml/Dev']
```

Into one list, My expected output is

```
['arn:aws:iam::****:saml/Prod', 'arn:aws:iam::***:saml/Test', 'arn:aws:iam::*****:saml/Dev']
```

into one list.

How can I do this? appreciate your help

Comment: Add some more information. Where are these strings coming from. Are you reading them from a file? If so, how?

Comment: These strings are coming from a variable                                                                                 my_list: ['arn:aws:iam::=:saml/Prod']                                                                                          my_list: ['arn:aws:iam:::saml/Test ']                                                                                      my_list: ['arn:aws:iam:::saml/Dev']

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "my_list" really is just a list of lists that each include a single string, your easiest answer is a list comprehension:

```
In [14]: my_list = [
    ...: ['arn:aws:iam::****:saml/Prod'],
    ...: ['arn:aws:iam::***:saml/Test'],
    ...: ['arn:aws:iam::*****:saml/Dev']
    ...: ]

In [15]: new_list = [item[0] for item in my_list]

In [16]: new_list
Out[16]:
['arn:aws:iam::****:saml/Prod',
 'arn:aws:iam::***:saml/Test',
 'arn:aws:iam::*****:saml/Dev']
```

But, to echo the first comment, there could potentially be more context here that might require more dynamic handling, etc.